# Company name displayed instead of "https"

Tags: ssl, https

How can I show the company name (author of the certificate) instead of the plain "https" in the browser url input?

Comment: Do you mean SSL Certificate with Extended Validation (EV): http://www.symantec.com/en/hk/verisign/ssl-certificates/secure-site-ev?inid=vrsn_symc_ssl_SSEV ?

Comment: Yes, seems to be this one. Thanks!

Comment: @Dorin Grecu - take a look at Peter Gutmann's comments on EV certificates and the "PKI-me-harder" phenomenon. See [Extended Validation Certificate - Critcisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate#PKI-Me-Harder).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in comment above, the certificate you look for is SSL Certificate with Extended Validation (EV), which validates Domain ownership as well as Company identity.

This kind of SSL certificate is offered by quite a lot Certificate Authorities, such as Verisign and GoDaddy.

Reference: http://www.symantec.com/en/hk/verisign/ssl-certificates/secure-site-ev?inid=vrsn_symc_ssl_SSEV